# Initial value problem for a PDE - Notations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, linear-pde

Approaching to PDE theory I was introduced to initial value problems for the linear one-dimensional transport equation like 
$$\begin{cases}
u_t + cu_x = 0, &&x\in \mathbb{R},\,t>0 &&& (1) \\ \\
u(0,x) = g(x), && x\in \mathbb{R} &&& (2)
\end{cases}$$
where $u=u(t,x)$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a generic (possibly $C^1$) function.

I do not really understand what the conditions $x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0$ mean: Does the equality  $u_t + cu_x = 0$ just hold in $(0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ and not in the whole $[0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$?

By method of characteristics, I know that if $u=u(t,x)$ satisfies $u_t + cu_x = 0$ on $ (0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ then $u(t,x)=f(x-ct)$ on $ (0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ for an arbitrary $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. How do I have to use de IC $u(0,x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to conclude that $u=g(x−ct)$ in the whole $[0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$?

Many authors treat the problem like $(1)$ holds in the whole $[0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ and so they just plug in the initial condition to find that $u(t,x)=g(x-ct)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $t\geq0$.

Any hint would be really appreciated!

Comment: Yes, the condition "$t> 0$" means that we are only *requiring* the differential equation to hold in $(0, \infty)\times R$.  How ever that does not mean that the differential equation **cannot** hold for t= 0- it's just that we do not need to know whether it does or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, sir. But from the fact that $u=f(x-ct)$ on $(0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ and, also, $u(0,x)=g(x) \, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ how can I formally conclude that $u=g(x-ct)$ on the whole $[0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is explained by @user247327, equation (1) is only needed to hold on the interior of the area.

After using the method of characteristics to get $u(x, t) = f(x - ct)$ for some $f:\mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$, the next step is to prove that $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$. Since $u \in C(\mathbb{R} × [0, +∞))$, taking an arbitrary $t_0 \in [0, +∞)$, then $u(·, t_0) \in C(\mathbb{R})$. Note that $u(x, t_0) = f(x - ct_0)$, thus $f(x) = u(x + ct_0, t_0) \in C(\mathbb{R})$.

Now, because $u \in C(\mathbb{R} × [0, +∞))$ and $u|_{t = 0} = g$, then$$
g(x) = u(x, 0) = \lim_{t → 0^+} u(x, t) = \lim_{t → 0^+} f(x - ct) = f(x), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
i.e. $f = g$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alex! Some authors, like Salsa, say something like that: fix any $(\overline{x},\overline{t})$ with $\overline{t}>0$. Let $x = ct + x_0$ be the equation of the characteristic passing through $(\overline{x},\overline{t})$.Go back in time along this characteristic from $(\overline{x},\overline{t})$ until the point $(x_0, 0)$, of intersection with the $x$− axes. Since $u$ is constant along the characteristic and  $u(x_0, 0) = g (x_0)$ then $$u(\overline{x},\overline{t})=g(x_0)=g(\overline{x}-c\overline{t}).$$

Comment: But from $(1)$ I know that $u$ is constant along $x = ct + x_0$ just for $t>0$. So why the author says that the value of $u$ in $(\overline{x},\overline{t})$ is the same as the value in $(x_0,0)$? Here is the source Salsa (http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~jfbonder/libro/(Universitext_)Sandro_Salsa-Partial_Differential_Equations_in_Action_from_Modelling_to_Theory-Springer(2008).pdf) at page  158.

Comment: @eleguitar In fact, the continuity of $u$ on the area including the boundary implies the continuity of $\overline u$ along the characteristic line including end points.

Comment: With $\overline{u}$ do you mean $\overline{u}(t)=u(ct+x_0,t)\,\,\,\forall t \in[0,+\infty)$?

Comment: So, finally, following your answer, since $u$ is supposed to be continuous then $$u(x_0,0)=\lim_{t \to 0^+}{u(ct+x_0,t)}=u(\overline{x},\overline{t}),$$ where the last equality holds because $u$ is constant along characteristics. Is that true?

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. That was illuminating to me. I should have thought about that. Thank your for your patience!

Comment: @eleguitar You're welcome :)